# Метод для складывания цифр числа

Tags: javascript

Если ли метод для складывания цифр числа?

Например:

```
15 = 1 + 5 = 6
```

или

```
584 = 5 + 8 + 4 = 17
```

Comment: Вот интересно кто `-1` поставил? Человек задал корректный вопрос, то что вопрос простой значит не надо задавать?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan формально "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален". Возможно, это кому-то не понравилось.

Comment: во втором варианте, где получилось 17, не надо снова сложить 1 и 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно брать остатки и округлять:

```
function digsum(n) {
  var sum = 0;
  while(n) sum += n % 10, n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  return sum;
}

digsum(15)  // 6
digsum(584) // 17
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function sum(a) {
  return a.toString().split('').reduce(function(a, b) { return a + parseInt(b); }, 0);
}

console.log(sum(584))
```

ES2015

```js
function sum(a) {
  return a.toString().split('').reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b), 0);
}

console.log(sum(584))
```

Comment: Ответ не плохой, но было бы не плохо дать пояснение, как реализован механизм функции. Ну, к примеру, [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - разбивает строку на массив строк, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - применяет функцию к каждому значению массива, слева-направо, сводя его к одному значению. А так +1 :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov согласен с вами. Торопился, хотел блеснуть умом. В свою очередь плюсую ваш комментарий, так как он добавляет полезную информацию к сообщению.

Comment: Можно, кстати, чуток укоротить код, если использовать `+b` вместо `parseInt(b)`. Но это уже больше "кол-во символов" vs "простота понимания кода".

Answer (score 2):

готового метода вроде как нет, можно написать самому, разбить строку на символы и сложить их

```
function sum(number) {
     var digits,
         sum = 0;
     if(Object.prototype.toString.call(number) == '[object Array]') {
       // из комментов - либо (number instanceof Array)
       digits = number;
     } else {
       digits = number.toString().split('')
     }

     for(var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
         sum += parseInt(digits[i]);
     }
     return sum;
}
```

Comment: а если у нас массив?

Comment: в условиях не сказано было ;) сейчас поправим

Comment: @user255352 `а если у нас массив?` - ты не знаешь что такое циклы и как подсчитать сумму всех чисел используя его? может тогда книжечку почитаешь по базам языка?

Comment: Алексей читаю))) спасибо за ответи

Comment: @maxkrasnov я как то не понял логику обновленной версии вашего ответа? мне кажется не правильно работает.

Comment: Проверку на массив хотелось бы понадёжнее чем просто `typeof` равно `'object'`.

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan был дан коммент, что параметром может приходить массив, вот я и проверяю массив это или нет, js через typeof видит его как объект

Comment: @maxkrasnov, лучше через `instanceof` проверяй

Comment: @maxkrasnov я вопрос задал не про проверку а про логику? что выводит ваша функция если ему дать массив?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan у меня там только один return, и он возвращает сумму

Comment: @maxkrasnov а не надо отдельно для каждого элемента массива?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan это если передаётся массив чисел, каждое из которых нужно отдельно обработать. А если передаётся массив цифр одного числа, то всё ровно так, как в данном ответе. Автор вопроса вообще напрасно про это в комментариях написал - надо было изначально полностью и понятно описывать вопрос.

Comment: а автор вопроса думал что это и так понятно всем))) получается нет))

Comment: @user255352, что именно понятно? что вместо числа, на вход может попасть что угодно?

Comment: ага. именно так. почему не сделать глобальнее?

Comment: @user255352 во-первых, вопрос был про конкретное число. Во-вторых, функция, в качестве параметра которой передаётся "что угодно"  и которая потом по фактическому типу параметра определяет что делать, - это плохая функция. Поэтому для этого нужна отдельная функция, которая опять-таки будет лишней в рамках вопроса. Алгоритм суммирования цифр числа, оформленный в виде отдельной функции, приведён в ответах. Как и для чего использовать эту функцию - это уже ваше право/дело.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function f(x) { // Нормальный
  for (var res = 0; x; x = Math.floor(x / 10)) res += x % 10;
  return res  
}

function g(x) { // Короткий
  return [...(""+x)].reduce((r, c) => r + +c, 0)
}

console.log(f(1234), g(1234))
console.log(f(0), g(0))
console.log(f(1), g(1))
console.log(f(65536), g(65536))
```

Answer (score 0):

Такого метода нет.

```js
function digits_sum(number){
  let result = 0;
  for(let i = 1; i<number; i=i*10)
      result += ((number-number%i)/i)%10;
  return result;
}

console.log(digits_sum(1234));
console.log(digits_sum(88));
console.log(digits_sum(5555555555));
```

Comment: Код некорректно работает для чисел `1`, `10`, `100` и т.д. Должно быть  `i <= number`. Насчет `i = i * 10` вместо `i *= 10` и экономии на пробелах - это уже дело субъективное.