# javascript создание нового массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив чисел `[65, 44, 12, 4]`, Мне надо получить новый массив в котором будет сложение цифр каждого элемента массива.

Как поправить мой код?

```js
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  while (numbers[i] > 0) {
    sum += numbers[i] % 10;

    numbers[i] = Math.floor(numbers[i] / 10);
  }
}
document.write(sum);
```

Comment: И какой ответ дать на этот вопрос?

Comment: я хочу чтобы создалься новый массив, но код дает мне только одну цифру

Comment: хочу узнать что неправильно в коде

Comment: что значит "чтобы создался новый массив"? что там должно быть?

Comment: sum - это число, ты выводишь число. откуда должен появиться новый массив - непонятно. Какие в нем должны быть значения - непонятно

Comment: @user255352 Это надо написать в вопросе, и вообще здесь у вас нет закрывающего тега `</script>`

Comment: тег на самом деле есть.  смотрите я хотел чтобы этот код создал вот такой массив [11, 8, 3, 4] но он сложит все и дает результат 26

Comment: эти числа от балды?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, суммы цифр чисел :-) смотри предыдущие вопросы автора

Comment: @Grundy теперь понятно

Comment: нет это обичные числа

Comment: @user255352 это необычные числа))

Comment: @user255352 вопрос надо задать так.

Comment: возьмите листок бумаги и карандаш и выполните вручную действия Вашего кода - все станет понятно

Answer (score 3):

Ты используешь неверный подход. В прошлом вопросе [@Sergiks](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681838/186999) дал функцию, которая вычислит сумму цифр для одного числа. (вместо нее можно взять любую другую функцию из ответов)

Теперь, тебе надо взять эту функцию и *применить ко всем числам в массиве*.

Для этого подходит метод [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), который и вернет новый массив:

```js
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];

function digsum(n) {
  var sum = 0;
  while (n) sum += n % 10, n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  return sum;
}

var result = numbers.map(digsum);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: кто бы сомневался, что Grundy может это сделать!

Comment: @Igor, что именно? :-)

Comment: это javascript?

Comment: @Grundy Выполнить задание.

Comment: "это javascript?" - это "пять"!

Comment: JSON.stringify(result)

Comment: z nfrjuj yt gjvy.

Comment: я такого не помню вроде

Comment: @user255352, это только для того, чтобы массив вывелся в виде `[1,2,3]` а не просто числа через запятую.

Comment: осмотрим сейчас

Comment: спасибо но посмотрим что получится

Answer (score 0):

немного усовершенствовал. теперь можно так
`[655, 449, 12, 4]` => `[7, 8, 3, 4 ]`.

```js
var numbers = [655, 449, 12, 4];

digsum = (number) => {
  // если одно число то возврат значения
  if (number.toString().length === 1) {
    return number;
  }
  
  // делаем массив из чисел
  const tmp = number.toString().split('');
  
  // складываем 
  let sum = tmp.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
    // небольшой кастыль приведения к числу так как в массиве лежат строки
    return +previousValue + +currentValue;
  });
  
  // если сумма получилась двойного порядка 
  sum = digsum(sum);
    
  return sum;
}

var result = numbers.map(digsum);

console.log(result);
```

но если все таки надо так
`[655, 449, 12, 4]` => `[16, 17, 3, 4]`. 
то вот

```js
var numbers = [655, 449, 12, 4];

digsum = (number) => {
  // если одно число то возврат значения
  if (number.toString().length === 1) {
    return number;
  }
  
  // делаем массив из чисел
  const tmp = number.toString().split('');
  
  // складываем 
  let sum = tmp.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
    // небольшой кастыль приведения к числу так как в массиве лежат строки
    return +previousValue + +currentValue;
  });
      
  return sum;
}

var result = numbers.map(digsum);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: для суммирования цифр числа ( и снова, если `sum > 9`) есть красивое решение с остатком от деления на 9: `function digsum(n) {
      var s = n % 9;
      return s === 0 ? 9 : s;
    }`

Comment: @Sergiks ты думаешь нахождение остатка от деления будет оптимальнее (в производительности) чем просто разбить строку?

Comment: 1. jsperf.com вам в помощь, хотя об экономии на спичках тут речи пока не было;
2. две строки кода понятнее и красивее макарон с повтором перевода числа в строку и работы с объектом массива вместо числа.

Comment: upd. ваш вариант [катастрофически медленнее](https://jsperf.com/sum-of-digits/1) предложенного мной остатка от деления. ![скрин теста](http://i.imgur.com/xwJIbgs.png) – 4 млн. оп/сек vs. 66 тыс. оп/с по вашему варианту ))

Comment: @Sergiks да ваш вариант хорош. но мой тоже имеет право на существование :) . я просто не вкурил еще как ваш код работает

Comment: дело не в коде, а в теории чисел )  Не учёл ещё нулевой случай - если просто 0 на входе - результат не 9, а 0 должен быть: `function digsum(n) { var s = n % 9; return s === 0 ? (n===0 ? 0 : 9) : s; }`

Comment: @Sergiks последний вариант немного лапшеватый получился :)

Comment: @Sergiks про это алгоритм где можно по подробнее прочитать ?
а то я щас не поверишь, сижу уже почти на спичках просчитываю алгоритм

Comment: @Sergiks все вкурил :) спасибо это инструмент хорош